# 'That's a good one, isn't it/that?' -- Question Tag after Demonstratives

Tags: grammar

Regarding the question in the title, I think we should use *it*:

> That's a good one, isn't *it*?

'Isn't *that*' is respectively rare in this position, but I'm not sure if it's incorrect.

My question is: should we always use *it* in the question tag instead of *this* or *that*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With *This/That* we use *it* in the question tag. So the usage of *isn't it* in the question tag is right.

When *These/Those* is used in the main sentence, the sentence requires *They* in the question tag. For Ex. *These are good, aren't they?*

[Source](https://englishwithjennifer.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/theres-a-lot-to-remember-when-teaching-tag-questions-isnt-there/)

Comment: I was hoping for a reference to call it downright _wrong_ to use "isn't that?" as a question tag, but I guess this and my thorough search in the web should be enough now. Thnx. +1.

Comment: Usage of "isn't that" in question tag is wrong. I have never seen it being used this way.  @MJF